# How can I find a deleted URL?

Tags: url

I have a URL of a tumblr picture that was deleted this morning, and I want to get the picture back. Because it's just one picture, it hasn't been stored in something like the wayback machine.

Is there a way to recover it?

Comment: No if its been deleted and not been viewed by a crawler the. What you want is not possible

Comment: There's lots of different places where content might be cached. Here's one list of caching sites: http://www.searchengineshowdown.com/others/archive.shtml I don't think there's one single place where the entire internet is saved.

Answer (score 1):

Not really.  Unless you can contact tumblr to see if they still have the photo stored somewhere, which is unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

Have access to a PC that viewed it before it was deleted? Perhaps it is in that PC's local cache. Cache location dependent upon OS and browser flavors.

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to be using Chrome, Opera or another Blink-based browser, there is `browser://view-http-cache`. Open that address and look for the URL of the image. If you can find it, then you most probably will see the image in binary form, in which case it may be restored.

Edit: I assume that the image has been online and was taken down and you are asking for a way to view it again. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: about:view-http-cache